# How to filter Object using select option

Tags: typescript, object

I have a object with some enum values in code. And when i try to filter it using select option. Here is snippet:

```
export enum BranchRegion {
  A = "A",
  B = "B",
  C = "C",
  R = "R"
}
```

And my ts file:

```
branchRegion = Object.keys(BranchRegion);
```

And html:

```
<select
  class="form-control"
  name="region"
  formControlName="region"
  id="field_region"
  [class.is-invalid]="
    branchForm.get('region').invalid &&
    (branchForm.get('region').dirty ||
      branchForm.get('region').touched)
  "
  (change)="filterLocations($event.target.value)"
>
  <option *ngFor="let item of branchRegion" [value]="item">{{
    branchRegionLabel[item]
  }}</option>
</select>
```

And function is:

```
 filterLocations(value: any) {
    Object.keys(this.branchRegion).every(value);
    console.log(this.branchRegion);
  }
```

And result:

[image]

What am i doing wrong ? Any advice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to see what you are trying to do in the `filterLocations` method. The `this.branchRegion` is already an array. So doing `Object.keys()` on it is a bit over the top :). Maybe you want to do something like this? By doing the `Object.keys` over the source object makes sure you do not filter on a filtered array

```
filterLocations(value: any) {
  this.branchRegion = Object.keys(BranchRegion).filter((region) => region === value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception you are getting is from this line:

`Object.keys(this.branchRegion).every(value);`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every
`Array.every` - The every() method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

You are not providing a function to every.

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem:

```
Object.keys(this.branchRegion).every(value);
```

Every expects a callback function, and you gave it a value. If you want to filter only selected items then use the filter method:

```
Object.keys(this.branchRegion).filter(v => v === value);
```